# How to hide the URL address bar in android browser ? with or without binding java script and android code?

Tags: android, url, android-webview

I want to hide the URL address bar of website in my android application but don't know how to do it.I have done some Google research but didn't get the concept .Please if someone can help me in this. Thanks

Here is my MainActivity Code:

```
package com.example.androidapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu; 

class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String url = "http://m.example.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);

            -----------------

            -----------------

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: You use an intent to start an external activity to display the web page, you can't modify this external activity. You could use a webview instead to achieve the desired effect

Answer (score -1):

You need to use webiview in your application to hide URL address bar

See here example : 
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Thanks

Comment: I don't want to add any button in my app . i just  want when i run the app it opens the desire URL without showing the address bar

Comment: you can directly load URL without button click.